# Open terminal in current directory with tmux

Tags: command-line, bashrc, tmux

I have a simple `.bashrc` file at the moment that allows me to always open the same terminal (reopen, actually) running tmux. The important part is shown below.

The essence of this is that when you execute `tmux attach -d` you disconnect any `tmux` session that is running, effectively closing the terminal window that is open (since I opened it with the `tmux`command). `tmux` is still running however, so calling a terminal with `tmux attach -d` reopens that session thanks to a little line in the tmux config file.

This works great but now I'd like to have the functionality back that opens a terminal window in the directory where I click "open terminal here".

I understand I would have to to the following:

1. Tell `tmux` to "C-m C" (create new panel)
2. `cd` to the current directory

Is this possible? I have a very limited knowledge of this sort of things, hence I'm asking.

I have been looking around and found [this gist](https://gist.github.com/dmytro/4129656) (also shown below). It makes sense but I don't know how to get the `${TARGET}` variable inside the `.bashrc` file.

**.bashrc**

```
116 # Start tmux every time we call up a terminal
117 [[ $TERM != "screen" ]] && exec tmux attach -d
```

**tmux.conf**

```
  1 #if run as "tmux attach", create a session if one does not already exist
  2 new-session -n $HOST
```

**The gist file**

```
tmux_pwd () {
    [ -z "${TMUX}" ] && return
    TARGET=\-t$(tmux display-message -p "#S")
    tmux set-window-option ${TARGET} default-path $PWD > /dev/null
    (( sleep 300;
    tmux set-window-option ${TARGET} default-path  ~/Development > /dev/null; ) & ) > /dev/null 2>&1
}
alias pwd="\pwd; tmux_pwd"
```

Answer (score 1):

Tmux always opens with your present working directory.

Like, if you are in /home/user/Desktop/, tmux session will start from this path only.

And please elaborate your question.

Comment: Actually, you can ask tmux to [open new windows in the same directory as the current pane](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109255/8503), although that may be unrelated to the OP's question.